# Как написать выборку из таблицы, где поле code соответствует маске?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql, postgresql9.5

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу сократить свою запись. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно компактнее написать выборку из таблицы table1, где поле code соответствует маске [что-то].1.[ноль или одна цифра]66|67|68|71|72|180|181|182|185|186|187|301

```
select *
from table1 
where code similar to '%\.1\._?66'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?67'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?68'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?71'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?72'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?180'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?181'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?182'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?185'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?186'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?187'
or code similar to '%\.1\._?301'
```

Результат:

```
1.1.066
1.1.067
1.1.067
1.1.068
1.1.071
1.1.071
1.1.072
1.1.072
1.1.166
1.1.166
1.1.167
1.1.168
1.1.168
1.1.171
1.1.172
1.1.172
1.1.180
1.1.180
1.1.181
1.1.182
1.1.182
1.1.185
1.1.186
1.1.187
1.1.187
1.1.266
1.1.267
1.1.268
1.1.271
1.1.272
1.1.301
2.1.066
2.1.067
2.1.068
2.1.068
2.1.071
2.1.072
2.1.072
2.1.166
2.1.166
2.1.167
2.1.167
2.1.168
2.1.168
2.1.171
2.1.171
2.1.172
2.1.172
2.1.180
2.1.180
2.1.181
2.1.182
2.1.182
2.1.185
2.1.186
2.1.187
2.1.187
2.1.271
2.1.272
2.1.301
```

Заранее благодарна!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from table1 
 where code ~ '.*\.1\.\d?(6[678]|7[12]|18[012567]|301)'
```

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KbzJZl/1)

Comment: Большое спасибо, @Mike !

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4), 64-bit

Comment: с similar to не выдал ни одного результата, заменила на ~, выдал всё, что нужно!